# I am getting Laravel Mysql Connection Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I get this error when I want to  **php artisan migrate**. The error message is as follows

> ```
>    Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> ```
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
> 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` bigint
> unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not
> null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp
> null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100)
> null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null)
> default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
>
> at
> C:\composer\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
> 667▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
> 668▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 669▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 670▕         catch (Exception $e) {   ➜ 671▕             throw new QueryException(
> 672▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 673▕             );
> 674▕         }
> 675▕
>
> 1
> C:\composer\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists")
>
> 2
> C:\composer\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
> PDOStatement::execute()

And Database settings are as follows.
The settings in the **Database.php** file are as follows

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

The settings in the **.env** file are as follows

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:sBKduFaKhOJdg7/A1U4IzAUnj3yLLcjngjmMvEoWl94=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**Note:** I use mysql for wampserver.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. `1050 Table 'users' already exists"` can you see error it is saying `users` already exites so can't create again  or you can try `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Comment: I've already tried this, nothing changes. Keeps giving error

Comment: manfully delete users table

Comment: php artisan db:wipe (it will drop all tables from db), and then php artisan migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove already migrated files, then execute migration command

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps i took to solve the same issue like:

1. In the console i wrote  =>  **php artisan tinker**
2. Then again in console   =>  **Schema::drop('users')**
3. At the end              =>  **php artisan migrate**

Comment: When it does what you say, it gives this error.


SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

Comment: Update your `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` to contain:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
`public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}`

Answer (score 0):

maybe below command will help!

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

**migrate command and their uses**

```
  migrate:fresh        Drop all tables and re-run all migrations
  migrate:install      Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh      Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset        Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback     Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status       Show the status of each migratioin
```

Comment: Could you expand you answer to include what this command does?

Answer (score 0):

just go to php path in windows you will find it here

Path to php in windows
`C:\tools\php82\php.ini`

then uncomment whatever you want for php extensions
for me i uncommented pdo_mysql and sqlite and worked fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, you should update `AppServiceProvider.php`.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot(): void {
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191); 
}
```